# Open single popup on table row click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck in a issue,

I have created one **custom table**, in **each td** of table row it **has a action button**,
**onclick()** of **action** it **open** a **small menu**.

But it **never closes** the **pervious open menu**, in-fact **open multiple menu**.

How to **close previous** and **open only one menu**.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, which may help you:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const clickOutside = useRef(null);
  const [showHideMenu, setShowHideMenu] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOutside = (event, ref) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      if (showHideMenu) setShowHideMenu(!showHideMenu);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) =>
      handleClickOutside(event, clickOutside)
    );
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div ref={clickOutside}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setShowHideMenu(!showHideMenu)}>Show Hide</button>
      <button onClick={() => setShowHideMenu(!showHideMenu)}>Show Hide</button>
      <button onClick={() => setShowHideMenu(!showHideMenu)}>Show Hide</button>
      <div>{showHideMenu ? "show" : "hide"}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Actually, this code works as you want. Whenever you click outside of your button, it'll automatically close all other popups.

Here is the [code sandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wescoff-g4cbd?file=/src/App.js:369-378)